# List all column names in every table in a database

Tags: pyspark, schema, databricks

I have a task to list all column names in every table in a database called 'trial_db'

I was able to get all table names from the following code :

```py
# Creating an empty DF (This is kind of an Hack...)
tbl_df = spark.sql("show tables in trial_db like 'xxx'")
# Loop through all databases
for db in spark.sql("show databases like 'trial_db'").collect():
  # create a dataframe with list of tables from the database
  df = spark.sql(f"show tables in {db.databaseName}")
  # union the tables list dataframe with main dataframe 
  tbl_df = tbl_df.union(df)
  
# After the loop, show the results
tbl_df.show()
```

I would like now to include the column names in each table and I tried the following :

```
def create_df(table_df):
    table_df= table_df.withColumn("database", df.database.cast(String))
    table_df= table_df.withColumn("table", df.table.cast(String))
    table_df= table_df.withColumn("columns", df.columns.cast(string))

    return table_df

# Loop through all databases
for db in spark.sql("show databases like 'trial_db'").collect():
  # Get list of tables in the database
  tables = spark.sql(f"show tables in {db.databaseName}").rdd.map(lambda row: row.tableName).collect()
  
  # For each table, get list of columns
  for table in tables:
    columns = [c.name for c in spark.sql(f"describe {table}").collect()]
    # Create a dataframe with database, table, and columns information
    df = spark.createDataFrame([(db.databaseName, table, columns)], schema=['database', 'table', 'columns'])
    # Union the dataframe with main dataframe 
    tbl_df = tbl_df.union(df)

# After the loop, show the results
tbl_df.show()
```

But I get the following error :

```
AnalysisException: Table or view not found: countrycurrency_csv; line 1 pos 9;
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AnalysisException                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-1607350> in <module>
     16   # For each table, get list of columns
     17   for table in tables:
---> 18     columns = [c.name for c in spark.sql(f"describe {table}").collect()]
     19     # Create a dataframe with database, table, and columns information
     20     df = spark.createDataFrame([(db.databaseName, table, columns)], schema=['database', 'table', 'columns'])

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in sql(self, sqlQuery)
    775         [Row(f1=1, f2='row1'), Row(f1=2, f2='row2'), Row(f1=3, f2='row3')]
    776         """
--> 777         return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
    778 
    779     def table(self, tableName):

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
```

Comment: When you write *I get an error*, the very next thing that goes into your post should be the **complete, exact** error message. It's on the screen right in front of you, but we can't see that screen from here. You're asking us for free help to solve **your** problem, and it's in your best interest to make it as easy as possible for us to give it to you by providing the details you already have. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Answer (score 1):

You are not far from the solution. You are encountering an error because you are not specifying on which database you want to query the table using `DESCRIBE`. Also, your first *hack* query is giving you the following schema :

```py
#Creating an empty DF (This is kind of an Hack...)
tbl_df = spark.sql("show tables in trial_db like 'xxx'")

tbl_df.printSchema()
root
 |-- database: string (nullable = false)
 |-- tableName: string (nullable = false)
 |-- isTemporary: boolean (nullable = false)
```

While the target schema is :

```py
root
 |-- database: string (nullable = true)
 |-- table: string (nullable = true)
 |-- columns: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

as the column of columns is going to be an array of string that are the column names.

My solution would then be :

```py
#Creating an empty DF with defined schema (instead of your "Hack")
schema = "database string, table string, columns array<string>"
tbl_df = spark.createDataFrame([],schema)
 
# Loop through all databases
for db in spark.sql("show databases like 'trial_db'").collect():
  # Get list of tables in the database
  tables = spark.sql(f"show tables in {db.databaseName}").rdd.map(lambda row: row.tableName).collect()
  
  # For each table, get list of columns
  for table in tables:
    # You need to specify which database you want to use before describing the table. 
    # Especially if you are looping on several databases.
    spark.sql(f"use {db.databaseName}") 
    
    # Create an array of columns
    columns = [c.col_name for c in spark.sql(f"describe {table}").collect()]
    # Create a dataframe with database, table, and columns information
    df = spark.createDataFrame([(db.databaseName, table, columns)], schema=['database', 'table', 'columns'])
    # Union the dataframe with main dataframe 
    tbl_df = tbl_df.union(df)
```

Here is an example of result using the public "databricks" database.

```py
# After the loop, show the results
tbl_df.show()

+----------+--------------+--------------------+
|  database|         table|             columns|
+----------+--------------+--------------------+
|databricks| airlineflight|[Year, Month, Day...|
|databricks|  airlineplane|[tailnum, type, m...|
|databricks|bikesharingday|[instant, dteday,...|
|databricks|      citydata|[rankIn2016, stat...|
|databricks|databricksblog|[authors, categor...|
|databricks|     ipgeocode|[startingIP, endi...|
|databricks|     people10m|[id, firstName, m...|
|databricks|      ssanames|[firstName, gende...|
+----------+--------------+--------------------+
```

Also, You are not using the create_df defined function.